# Making a triangle using characters from the user input in java programing

Tags: java, string

I am new to coding and using java. I have been working on this java code for quite awhile now and I just cannot figure it out. I am trying to write a program that takes as input a string, and it outputs the string in a sequence of lines, first character, then next two characters, then next three characters and so on. But the last line could be short depending on the size of the original string. An example output would be:

```
String? abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
a
bc
def
ghij
klmno
pqrstu
vwxyz01
23456789
```

This is what I have down right now, I have tried a few things

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrianglingPhrase {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // declare variables
      String phrase;
      int start = 0;

      // get input
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("String? ");
      phrase = scan.nextLine();

      while(start < phrase.length()) {
         String row = phrase.substring(start, start + 1);

         start++;

         System.out.println(row);
      }
   }
}
```

Also this is the output I get with this code:

```
String? abc123
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

Comment: What is the output of your current code? Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

whatever you do substring(start, start+1) may only produce strings of length 1. So at least this has to grow continuously. With the var n in this case. It should stop to grow whenever it start+n>length()

```
int n=0;

while(start < phrase.length()) {
  n++;
  if(start+n > phrase.length())
    n=phrase.length()-start;
  String row = phrase.substring(start, start + n);
  start+=n;
  System.out.println(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are the so called  [triangle numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) You can model them with i*(i+1)/2. Start keeps track of the where the old end was so you can do this:

```
int start = 0;
    int end = 1;

    for (int i = 2; end <= phrase.length(); i++) {


        String row = phrase.substring(start, end);

        System.out.println(row);
        start = end;
        end = (i * (i + 1) / 2);
    }
}
```